# Rails ActiveRecord Access association's(children?) latest created objects

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

as title said i am trying to access an array of objects of an association 
This is a has_many association

here is my class

```
class Keyword < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :rankings
end


class Ranking < ApplicationRercord
    belongs_to :keyword
end
```

There are a attribute in ranking called position:integer, i want to be able to access all latest created rankings from all keyword here is what i got so far

```
Keyword.all.joins(:rankings).select( 'MAX(rankings.id) ').pluck(:created_at, :keyword_id, :position)
```

i've read some other post suggesting me to use MAX on rankings.id, but i am still not able to return the array

At the moment Keyword.count return 4597
Ranking.count return 9245

Each keyword has generated about 2 rankings, but i just want the latest ranking from each keyword in array format, so to get latest of each i should expect around 4597

Not sure if i explained clear enough, hope u guys can help me :'( thanks really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enough rankings you might want to store the latest ranking on the on keywords table as a read optimization:

```
class Keyword < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :latest_ranking, class_name: :ranking
   has_many :rankings, after_add: :set_latest_ranking

   def set_latest_ranking(ranking)
     self.update!(latest_ranking: ranking)
   end
end

Keyword.joins(:latest_ranking)
       .pluck(:created_at, :id, "rankings.position")
```

This makes it both very easy to join and highly performant. I learned this after dealing with an application that had a huge row count and trying every possible solution like lateral joins to improve the pretty dismal performance of the query.

The cost is an extra write query when creating the record.

Comment: yeah at the end i did this, seems like the simplest way to solve my problem. thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Postgres**. You can use **DISTINCT ON**

```
Keyword.joins(:rankings)
       .select("DISTINCT ON(ratings.keyword_id) keywords.*, ratings.position, ratings.created_at AS rating_created_at")
       .order("ratings.keyword_id, ratings.id DESC")
```

Now you can access `position`, `rating_created_at`

```
@keywords.each do |k|
  k.position
  ....

@keywords.map { |k| [k.id, k.rating_created_at, k.position] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Keyword.joins(:rankings).group("keywords.id").pluck("keywords.id", "MAX(rankings.id)")
```

This will give you an array which elements will include an ID of a `keyword` and an ID of the latest `ranking`, associated with that `keyword`.

If you need to fetch more information about `rankings` rather than `id`, you can do it like this:

```
last_rankings_ids_scope = Ranking.joins(:keyword).group("keywords.id").select("MAX(rankings.id)")

Ranking.where(id: last_rankings_ids_scope).pluck(:created_at, :keyword_id, :position)
```